# Network errors with Python Telegram Bot

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I use a Python Telegram Bot script in Visual Studio Code on my PC, and **sometimes** i have this error:

```
telegram.ext.dispatcher - ERROR - No error handlers are registered, logging exception. Traceback (most recent call last):
connectionpool.py", line 614, in urlopen httplib_response = self._make_request(conn, method, url,
connectionpool.py", line 402, in _make_request six.raise_from(e, None)
connectionpool.py", line 398, in _make_request httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
client.py", line 1322, in getresponse response.begin()
client.py", line 303, in begin version, status, reason = self._read_status()
client.py", line 264, in _read_status line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
socket.py", line 669, in readinto return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
ssl.py", line 1099, in read return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054]


telegram.error.NetworkError: urllib3 HTTPError ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, "Connessione in corso interrotta forzatamente dall'host remoto", None, 10054, None))
```

I follow [this link](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Handling-network-errors) and i tried to modify the **updater** in this way, but the problem persists:

```
updater = Updater(token='MYTOKEN', use_context=True, request_kwargs={'read_timeout': 6, 'connect_timeout': 7})
```

Running the script on my Android phone with 4G connetion, i haven't this error. So i think is my ADSL connection, maybe not stable.

What can i try to resolve this problem? Maybe modify some parameters in the updater?

Comment: Could it be your bot exceed request limits to telegram API and connection reset?

Comment: no @Sugar , the problem appears also when i don't use it. On my Android with 4G connection i haven't this problem

Comment: So it seems either your provider changing your IP address, or you have other issues with your configuration. Probably you should hook on connection reset and spin reconnect routine with short timeout and run it until back online.